# SIGSEGV Error occurs on the actual device but not on ios simulator

Tags: ios, crash, uiimageview, nsarray, segmentation-fault

I am the developer of a cydia tweak named CountdownCenter. I was trying to create a digital clock appearance for my widget, so I created a sample app that does this perfectly. After doing this, I transferred this data into the code of my tweak but, this causes a SIGSEGV crash on my iPhone. After some testing, I found the part that is responsible for the crash, but I just can't find what's wrong as this part would work on a normal app. Can you help me please?

Here is the code:

```
int digitarray[10];
    int c = 0;
    digitarray[0] = 0;
    digitarray[1] = 0;
    while (secon>0) {
        int digitt = secon % 10;
        digitarray[c] = digitt;
        secon /= 10;
        c++;
    }
        lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", digitarray[0]];
          [self selectimage:digitarray[0] img:numview10];
```

Answer (score 0):

`SIGSEGV` usually means, that you're trying to access memory, that you are not allowed to access. (btw are you testing this with a release build?) Maybe f.e. here (there are some other similar places too):

```
c = 0;
while (secon>0) {
    int digitt = secon % 10;
    digitarray[c] = digitt;
    secon /= 10;
    c++;
}
```

There are some possibilities:

- `secon` (horrible variable names btw...) is a `float` or `double`, in that case the `while loop` is either never entered or never left
- c becomes so large that it's beyond `digitarray`'s bounds

To solve this issue I would recommend to but a breakpoint at the beginning of your code and check it step by step.

Comment: Hey thanks, turns out that you were right, there were more than one bugs but the most significant was that it was writing out of bounds. Now, can you help me once more? A SIGABRT error occurs every time the secon goes from 0 to 9 again (the number reduces by 1 every second from 60 to 0, but every time it goes to a new set of 10 numbers it crashes with SIGABRT why? I will edit for you to see the more updated code. The text that I see in the label is correct by the way and this is why the whole thing is a bit strange...

Comment: (c and the array are initialised in the method as they didn't actually need to be global as they were in the original code)